# Central heating pipe to split into 2 runs

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture

Looking at splitting a feed and return line into 2 branches.

I have come up with 2 different manifold ideas but I am wondering what would be better to get equal pressure for each.

I have actually made option A but after making it I am not convinced that it will pass through the water equally (i.e the first pipe out will receive water first then once all through the second pipe out will get water)

As this is for central heating does it really matter? Would it mean one radiator gets hotter first?

[image: Manifold design]

Thanks
Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this piping is for a forced water heating system (a pump moves the water), then either piping diagram will work. If however it is for a parallel connection for pairing 2 or more water heaters and you need the same exact amount of flow to each unit then the right hand diagram is the only choice. In a heating system with a pump, The difference in the length of time for each branch to get hot will not be affected by either piping diagram but by the total length of each run of pipe and the total amount of radiation in each branch. I would recommend that if you are installing a new heating system in a building "zoning" would produce the best results. It would allow each zone or room to be controlled by it's own thermostat.

Comment: It is for a forced water heating system. I implemented option A last night and all worked as hoped.